# Call WCF Web Service in crm plugin

Tags: c#, wcf, crm

Can somebody help me access this web service? How am i going to call this service on my code? Will this work?

MyService.InputParameters input = new MyService.InputParameters();
input.attribute = " blah blah";

MyService.OutputParameteers = execute(input);
Thanks you !!!!

```
<wsdl:message name="requestMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="request" element="inp1:InputParameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="replyMessage">
   <wsdl:part name="reply" element="inp1:OutputParameters"/>
</wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:portType name="execute_ptt">
  <wsdl:operation name="execute">
   <wsdl:input message="tns:requestMessage"/>
    <wsdl:output message="tns:replyMessage"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
 </wsdl:portType>
```

Answer (score 0):

James,

I think this is what you are looking for.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-call-External-WCF-42c4490d

Hope this helps !!!